# Yield curve inversion and recession

Tags: economic-growth

Yield curve inversion is often a sign of a looming recession, but is there an explanation of this phenomenon other than the fact that historically we have seen that the two phenomena were indeed associated together.

Comment: Seems similar to https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/19904/why-is-the-inverted-yield-curve-a-good-predictor-of-impending-economic-recession